# How to provide the dynamic library used for blas for Theano on Google Colab?

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory, theano, blas, theano-cuda

As the title clearly describes the situation I'm facing, I'm getting the following warning on `Google Colab` while using the `Theano` as the backend of `Keras`:

```
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): We did not find a dynamic library in the library_dir of the library we use for blas. If you use ATLAS, make sure to compile it with dynamics library.
```

So, how can I provide the the dynamic library used for `blas` for `Theano` on `Google Colab`?

p.s. I've already installed the `Theano` package. The `libgpuarray`, and `pygpu` packages according to the [official documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/libgpuarray/installation.html).

Software Stack:

- `Keras` version: `2.3.1`.
- `Python` version: `3.6.9`.
- `Theano` version: `1.0.4`.

Comment: It is blas, not bias (l instead of i)

Answer (score 0):

could you try this?

```
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

!chmod +x Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

!bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local

import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')

#install theano and pygpu
!conda install theano pygpu
```

It downloads a host of dependencies which are used for theano.